# Can users see Silverlight code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, silverlight

I am thinking to use Silverlight instead of WPF as Client and WCF as server. Does it make sence?

I guess I will have these advantages:

1) More portable because it's Web.

2) I don't need to validate an user input in both client and server applications.

The third advantage is my main question: I guess the user cannot see my code, so my application would be safe against hackers. Is this correct? This means that if I store a database connection string in Silverlight, no clients will see it, right?

Thanks.

Comment: More portable... between Windows computers

Comment: @Serge: No, it also runs on Macs (officially supported by MS) and Linux (to some degree with Moonlight).

Comment: @H.B. : on iOS ??? MacOS you mean.

Comment: @H.B.: Could you provide a link to running Silverlight apps on the iPad, for example?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Err, whatever, those Apple computer thingies.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, sorry, i got that confused.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, probably I have too narrow look... Honestly speaking I don't like proprietary things at all, but this is another discussion

Comment: @Serge: I would say that free software is ideologically preferable, but WPF and SL5 have been the greatest GUI frameworks i have programmed in so far.

Comment: @H.B. I didn't meant the open source SW. I mean open source standards, like RFC, ISO and others, so you have an alternative to choose a different vendor for the same technology.

Comment: @Serge: MoonLight is implementing a public (open?) standard ...

Comment: Guys, please, it's an endless discussion, let's not escalate :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I do not think that anything about SL is open or public, C# however should be.

Comment: It's really easy to view silverlight code using xamlspy, previously known as silverlight spy. See http://xamlspy.com/ so it is clearly not safe storing a connectionstring in silverlight code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .xap file in which your Silverlight Application is packaged is only an archive that contains the DLLs of your application (rename it to .zip and see for yourself) so your code can still be decompiled by anyone who downloads the .xap.

As for your 2nd point, you should validate on the server. I could, for example, sniff the traffic and see that your application calls a WCF web service. From there I could make my own requests to your service without using your application. If you don't validate server-side bad things will happen.

Also, the "portability" of Silverlight is arguable, but yes I guess it is more portable than a .exe.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) More portable because it's Web.

Well you'd have to define what you meant by "web" here. It won't work (unless I've missed something) on iOS (using Safari), or Android devices, or probably some others. It's not "web" in the same way that, say, a pure HTML5 application is "web".

> 2) I don't need to validate an user input in both client and server applications.

That's only true if the server can "know" that the input really came from the client. If it's just a web request, it could be posted by anything. In my experience you should *always* validate on the server - client-side validation is there to make life easier for the user; server-side validation is to really enforce business rules.

> The third advantage is my main question: I guess the user cannot see my code, so my application would be safe against hackers. Is this correct?

No. The code is running on the user's machine; it will have been downloaded, and can be decompiled like any other .NET assembly.

Comment: @H.B.: Are you sure? Not MacOSX? I should have specified: "without installing a separate browser" - so I guess I really mean "in Safari on iOS" which is what the bulk of consumers would be using. Will edit that in.

Comment: As noted on the question that is what i meant. Well, your main point stands in any case, it's a bit more portable but still not as much as HTML based applications.

Comment: I completely agree about "NOT-WEB".It uses client resources. Seeing a plugin in a browser does not mean its web. (Flash,java applets,silverlight are member of plug-in family.They all are detachable). Beside this with HTML approach mean supporting JS, its also another client side technology. Some browsers still does not support them or support by different way. HTML5 also uses client resources depending on JS . What can we say ? World keeps turning and everything getting complicated. In my opinion its not good coming for our resources; In a browser many pages,there are dozens of AJAX asking..

Answer (score 1):

The assembly can *easily* be extracted and decompiled also you never can know that a request comes from your application if it runs on the client so do not even *think* about skipping server validation.